# Trouble setting UIKeyboard accessory view

Tags: ios, ios5, uikit, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have an instance of `UIToolbar` that contains a `UITextField` inside. I'd like to set the toolbar at an accessory view for the `UITextField` it contains.

The way I do this is as follows:

```
[myTextView setInputAccessoryView:myToolbar];
```

When I compile and run the code, the entire keyboard disappears when I press on the text field. I specifically made sure I am setting the `inputAccessoryView` and not the `inputView`. It seems like the whole input view just got replaced, without any explicit direction to do so.

Does anyone know a way to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's generally not good to put a text field in an input accessory view... What would be better is if you put the toolbar along the bottom of your view and then use `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` to move the toolbar with the keyboard...

In your viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillChange:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
```

And somewhere in your view controller's code:

```
-(void) keyboardWillChange:(NSNotification*)notify {

    CGRect endFrame;
    float duration = [[[notify userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue];
    [[[notify userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&endFrame];
    endFrame = [self.view convertRect:endFrame fromView:nil];
    float y = (endFrame.origin.y > self.view.bounds.size.height ? self.view.bounds.size.height-44 : endFrame.origin.y-44);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, y, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44);
    }];

}
```

Comment: this seems like what the built in Messages app is doing with the text input toolbar.

Comment: Yup I think so, and it's also an easy way of moving a fullscreen scroll view, text view or web view so that you can still scroll to the end even if the keyboard is covering it...

Comment: In this case, is endFrame there to make sure that I move the toolbar in the right direction? (up when the keyboard comes up and down when it disappears?)

Comment: Yes, `endFrame` tells your app where the keyboard will be whenever it moves, whether it's moving up or down...

Comment: There may not always be a `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`, e.g. when the user is sliding an undocked keyboard on iPad. In that case your `endFrame` will be uninitialized and contain garbage values.

Comment: Really? When I tested it, the top of the frame still pointed to the top of the keyboard, even when undocked and moving around, or split