# How to add a button on the top of default keyboard in iPhone?

Tags: uiview, uibutton, uikeyboard

I saw many iPhone apps contains some custom buttons over the default keyboard to perform some actions. See this image..

[image]

Here the arrow button was used to resign the keyboard.

**My doubts:**

- Should I make a custom keyboard for this? I can simply show the button separately on a fixed view over keyboard. But what about the show/hide animation. I want to show/hide the button with respect to the move of keyboard. Is it possible if I use the fixed view over keyboard?
- Will Apple reject my app if I customize the default keyboard behavior? (If yes, then how these apps are available in AppStore??)
- [Here](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/uikeyboardcoview) is a sample project that adds a UIButton in the top of the keyboard. But I dont want to make it with IB.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that, it is so simple to make those buttons with iOS 6 by the method `setInputAccessoryView:`. For below iOS6, we have to create some custom views and set their frame on the top of keyboard frame. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231219/trouble-setting-uikeyboard-accessory-view) for more information.